# Importing a constant PHP

Tags: php, drupal, constants

I have this file

```
namespace Drupal\api\ConfigArrays {

    const jsonApiUris = array(
        'insert_publication' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'uri' => 'node/publication'
        )
    );
}
```

But when i try to import in some class:

```
use const Drupal\api\ConfigArrays\jsonApiUris;

class HttpHelper
{

    static public function sendToJsonAPI($content, $endpoint, $token)
    {
        var_dump(jsonApiUris);
        die;       
    }

}
```

my IDE (PhpStorm) recognizes the variable and the autocomplete, but when I execute it, I get this error

> Error: Undefined constant 'Drupal\api\ConfigArrays\jsonApiUris' in
>   Drupal\api\Helpers\HttpHelper::sendToJsonAPI() (line 21 of
>   modules/custom/api/src/Helpers/HttpHelper.php).

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Also may want to try from the root namespace `use const \Drupal\api\Conf.....`

Comment: i'm using php 7.1, i know that my syntax just work in versions 5.6+.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine for PHP5.6+ but if you are running a prior version you'll need to use Drupal\api\ConfigArrays then access it via ConfigArrays\jsonApiUris

Are you sure the code in the first snippet has been included/defined by the time it reaches the second snippet?

Comment: i'm usign a version biggest than 5.6+ i'm using 7.1, but it that you say about if the first fragment is declare before that the second, i think that yes, because the file that content the class HttpHelper call de constant  "use const Drupal\api\ConfigArrays\jsonApiUris", or what do you mean when said that if i the first is declared before the second.

Comment: I think the code in the first snippet isn't getting loaded in. I've replicated your two snippets in a test php setup and the syntax is fine, the problem seems to be it's unaware of the contents of your first snippet. What file is it in, and are you sure it's being loaded into Drupal?

My test returns..
`array(1) { ["insert_publication"]=> array(2) { ["method"]=> string(4) "POST" ["uri"]=> string(16) "node/publication" } } `